# Media queries wont work properly (Tablet size works, Mobile doesnt)

Tags: css, media-queries

I don't get my media queries to work properly, from desktop to tablet it works fine, but it doesn't change the size from tablet to mobile (especially the H1).

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    min-height: 85%
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, a {
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #494949;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1, h2 {
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px #999999, 1px 0 #999999, 0 1px #999999, -1px 0 #999999;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-top: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

h4, p {
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
    color: #494949;
}

/* h1 padding as solution for the "jump to home" problem :h1 {padding-top: 2.5%} *******/

hr {
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #494949;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
}

#logo, li, img, .button {
    transition: all 300ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms;
    -o-transition: all 300ms
}

/* HEADER ********************************/

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #FEFCFB;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 1;
}

#logo {
    width: 140px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 -10px
}

#logo img {
    width: 56%;
}

#logo:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin: 6px 50px 0 0;
}

header nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

header nav ul li a {
    font-size: 16px
}

header nav ul li:hover {
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Header

#headerino {
 min-height: 10%
}
 ********************************/

/* Home ********************************/

#home {
    background: url(../img/landing.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#home h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 70px;
    font-size: 110px
}

#home h2 {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#home img {
    width: 32px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

#home img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#home {
    min-height: 100%
}

/* About ********************************/

#about img {
    width: 240px;
}

#about h4 {
    font-size: 15px;
}

#about p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#about img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* Kurzwarenmobil ********************************/

#DasKurzwarenmobil img {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#DasKurzwarenmobil {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    opacity: 1;
}

#DasKurzwarenmobil p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

#DasKurzwarenmobil img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* Ich bringe den Großhandel zu ihnen ********************************/

#Großhandel img {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#Großhandel img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#Großhandel p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

/* Service ********************************/

#service img {
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#service {
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    opacity: 1;
}

#service img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#service p {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

/* Contact  ********************************/

form input, textarea {
    font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color: #494949;
    outline: none;
}

form input {
    width: 552px;
    height: 30px
}

form textarea {
    width: 552px;
    height: 200px;
    resize: none;
    border-color: #494949;
}

.input_text {
    color: #494949;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.button {
    width: 566px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    color: #494949;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: #494949;
    color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Footer  ********************************/

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

footer p {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

/* Media Queries ********************************/

/* Tablets ********************************/

@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    #logo {
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    header nav {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    header nav ul li {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #home h1 {
        font-size: 65px;
    }
    #home h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    h3 {
        padding-top: 12%
    }
}

/* Mobile********************************/

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    #logo {
        width: 100px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    header nav {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    header nav ul li {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #home h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    #home h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    h3 {
        padding-top: 12%
    }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Header -->
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="img/111.jpg"="Kurzwarenmobil">
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href="#index">
        <li>home</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#about">
        <li>Über mich</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#DasKurzwarenmobil">
        <li>Das Kurzwarenmobil</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#Kontakt">
        <li>Kontakt</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<!-- Home -->
<section id="home">
  <h1>Kurzwarenmobil</h1>
  <h2>H.S. Schneiderbedarf</h2>
  <a href="#about">
    <img src="img/pfeil.png" alt="arrow">
  </a>
</section>
<!-- Über mich -->
<section id="about">
  <h3>Über mich</h3>
  <hr>
  <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Hüllis face">
  <h4>H.S Schneiderbedarf<h4>
      <p>
        Ich Bin Hülya S. und habe mittlerweile mehr als ein Jahrzent Erfahrung im Schneider- sowie Kurzwarengeschäft
        angesammelt.
        Meine Leidenschaft und Faszinierung der Branche gegenüber brachten mich
        nach jahrelangem arbeiten als Näherin in verschiedenen Unternehmen dazu, mich in dieser Branche selbstständig zu
        machen Nachdem die Entscheidung der Selbstständigkeit gefällt war, fing die Arbeit erst richtig an. Nach langem
        Konzeptionieren, Umsetzen, Verfeinern, Scheitern und wieder aufstehen war letzendlich die Idee des
        "Kurzwarenmobils" geboren.<br>Mittlerweile erstreckt sich mein Kundenstamm weit über die Grenzen Hannovers, den Heimatort des Kurzwarenmobils
        aus. Mittlerweile beläuft sich das Geschäft auf viele große sowie kleine Städte Norddeutschlands, und die
        Kapazitätsgrenze ist noch lange nicht erreicht.
      </p>
</section>
<!-- Kurzwarenmobil -->
<section id="DasKurzwarenmobil">
  <br>
  <h3>Das Kurzwarenmobil</h3>
  <hr>
  <img src="img/333.jpg" alt="INSERT IMG Hülli WAGEN+ Sie">
  <h4>Was Ist das Kurzwarenmobil?</h4>
  <p>
    Das Kurzwarenmobil ist mein Transporter, mit dem ich täglich verschiedene Städte Deutschlands besuche und meinen
    über 300 Kunden, die
    benötigten Utensilien und Stoffe direkt zu ihren Läden liefere.
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
</section>
<br>
<!-- großhandel--->
<section id="Großhandel">
  <h4>Ich bringe den Großhandel zu ihnen</h4>
  <img src="img/4444.jpg" alt="Großhandel">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>
    Da das Hauptgeschäft des Kurzwarenmobils auf die Mobilität und große Auswahl ausgelegt ist und ich die Waren direkt
    vom Großhandel beziehe,
    bin ich in der Lage die beste Ware zum günstigen Preis anzubieten. wodurch sie selbstverständlich bares Geld sparen
    können!<br>Umfangreiches Angebot und stets die aktuellsten Waren der Kurzwarenwelt, Ob Knöpfe und
    Reißverschlüsse für individuelle Modeschöpfungen, Handarbeitsgarne oder modische
    Bänder und Kordeln für kreative Deko-Ideen: Das Kurzwarenmobil führt stehts eine Große Auswahl an hochwertigen
    Arbeitsmaterialien und das ohne Einschränkung und in voller Ausführung direkt vor ihrer Tür!
    Durch regelmäßige Besuche und kostenloser Anfahrt können sie dadurch Einsparungen in ihren Lagerhaltungs- bzw
    Lieferungskosten einsparen.
  </p>
</section>
<!-- individueller service-->
<section id="service">
  <br>
  <h4>Individueller Service</h4>
  <img src="img/222.jpg" alt="Sortiment innen">
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>
    Durch die Natur meiner Arbeit haben sie nicht nur den Vorteil, dass ich ihnen alle benötigten Utensilien bis vor die
    Türe bringe, sondern auch das Privileg sich am gesamten Katalog des Kurzwarenmobils vor Ort inspirieren und
    individuell beraten zu lassen. Fehlerhafte Bestellung gehören damit der vergangenheit an!
  </p>
  <br>
</section>
<!-- Contact -->
<section id="Kontakt">
  <h3>Kontakt</h3>
  <hr>
  <form>
    <input class="input_text" type="email" tabindex="1" Placeholder="E-mail"><br><br>
    <input class="input_text" type="text" tabindex="2" Placeholder="Betreff"><br><br>
    <textarea class="input_text" tabindex="3" Placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea> <br><br>
    <input class="button" type="submit">
  </form>
</section>
<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
  <p>
    &copy; 2018-2019 B.Ertürk, All rights reserved
  </p>
</footer>
```

I don't get my media queries to work properly, from desktop to tablet it works fine, but it doesn't change the size from tablet to mobile (especially the H1).

```css
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; text-align: center;}
section { min-height: 85%}
a {text-decoration: none;}
li {list-style-type: none;}

h1, h2, h3,a { font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif ; font-weight: 500; color: #494949;text-transform: uppercase;}
h1, h2 {color: white;
text-shadow: 0 -1px #999999, 1px 0 #999999, 0 1px #999999, -1px 0 #999999;}
h3 {font-size: 40px; padding-top: 0%;margin-bottom: 5px;}
h4, p {font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif; color:#494949;}

/* h1 padding as solution for the "jump to home" problem :h1 {padding-top: 2.5%} *******/


hr {width: 100px;height: 3px;background: #494949;border: 0;margin: 0 auto 40px auto;}
#logo,li,img,.button {transition: all 300ms; -webkit-transition: all 300ms; -moz-transition: all 300ms; -o-transition: all 300ms}


/* HEADER ********************************/
header { width: 100%; height: 65px; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; background: #FEFCFB; box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ; z-index: 1; }

 #logo {

 width: 140px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px 0 0 -10px
 }

#logo img{

 width: 56%;


}

#logo:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}

 
header nav {

 float:right;
 margin:6px 50px 0 0;
}

header nav ul li {
 float:left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

header nav ul li a {
 font-size: 16px
}

header nav ul li:hover {
 padding-top: 5px;
}
/* Header

#headerino {
 min-height: 10%
}
 ********************************/





/* Home ********************************/


#home{
 background: url(../img/landing.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment:  fixed;
 }

#home h1 {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 70px;
 font-size: 110px}

#home h2 {
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 font-size: 25px;

}

#home img  {
 width: 32px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 opacity: 0.7;
}
#home img:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
#home {min-height: 100%}
/* About ********************************/


#about img {
 width: 240px;
}

#about h4{
 font-size: 15px;
}

#about p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;


}

#about img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* Kurzwarenmobil ********************************/

#DasKurzwarenmobil img {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 3px;


}
#DasKurzwarenmobil {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 opacity: 1;
}
#DasKurzwarenmobil p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 }

#DasKurzwarenmobil img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}



/* Ich bringe den Großhandel zu ihnen ********************************/
#Großhandel img {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 3px;}

 #Großhandel img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

#Großhandel p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
/* Service ********************************/
#service img {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#service {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 opacity: 1;
}
#service img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);}

#service p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 }

/* Contact  ********************************/


form input, textarea {
font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: #494949;
outline: none;
}

form input {

 width: 552px;
 height: 30px

}

form textarea {
 width: 552px;
 height: 200px;
 resize: none;
 border-color: #494949;
}


.input_text {
 color:#494949 ;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.button {

 width: 566px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 color: #494949;
}

.button:hover {

 background-color: #494949;
 color: #f0f0f0;

}

/* Footer  ********************************/


footer {

width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

footer p {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #f0f0f0;
 padding-top:30px;
}

/* Media Queries ********************************/






/* Tablets ********************************/

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){



#logo {
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}


header nav {
 margin-top: 10px;

}
header nav ul li {
 font-size: 12px;
}

#home h1 {
 font-size: 65px;
 

}

#home h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
}
h3 {padding-top: 12%
}

}
/* Mobile********************************/

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

#logo {
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}


header nav {
 margin-top: 10px;

}
header nav ul li {
 font-size: 12px;
}

#home h1 {
 font-size: 30px;
 

}

#home h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
}
h3 {padding-top: 12%
}

}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <!-- Header -->
   <header>
 
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="img/111.jpg"="Kurzwarenmobil">
    </div>

    <nav>
    
     <ul>
      <a href="#index"><li>home</li></a>
      <a href="#about"><li>Über mich</li></a>
      <a href="#DasKurzwarenmobil"><li>Das Kurzwarenmobil</li></a>
      <a href="#Kontakt"><li>Kontakt</li></a>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>


   <!-- Home -->
<section id="home">
     <h1>Kurzwarenmobil</h1>
     <h2>H.S. Schneiderbedarf</h2>
     <a href="#about">
     <img src="img/pfeil.png" alt="arrow">
     </a>
</section>


    <!-- Über mich -->

<section id="about">
    <h3>Über mich</h3>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Hüllis face">
    <h4>H.S Schneiderbedarf<h4>
    <p> 
     Ich Bin Hülya S. und habe mittlerweile mehr als ein Jahrzent Erfahrung im Schneider- sowie Kurzwarengeschäft angesammelt. 
    Meine Leidenschaft und Faszinierung der Branche gegenüber brachten mich
    nach jahrelangem arbeiten als Näherin in verschiedenen Unternehmen dazu, mich in dieser Branche selbstständig zu machen
    
    Nachdem die Entscheidung der Selbstständigkeit gefällt war, fing die Arbeit erst richtig an. Nach langem Konzeptionieren, Umsetzen, Verfeinern, Scheitern und wieder aufstehen war letzendlich die Idee des "Kurzwarenmobils" geboren.
    <br>

    Mittlerweile erstreckt sich mein Kundenstamm weit über die Grenzen Hannovers, den Heimatort des Kurzwarenmobils aus. Mittlerweile beläuft sich das Geschäft auf viele große sowie kleine Städte Norddeutschlands, und die Kapazitätsgrenze ist noch lange nicht erreicht.
   
   </p>
</section>


   <!-- Kurzwarenmobil -->

<section id="DasKurzwarenmobil">
    <br>
    <h3>Das Kurzwarenmobil</h3>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/333.jpg" alt="INSERT IMG Hülli WAGEN+ Sie">
    <h4>Was Ist das Kurzwarenmobil?</h4>
    <p>
     Das Kurzwarenmobil ist mein Transporter, mit dem ich täglich verschiedene Städte  Deutschlands besuche und meinen über 300 Kunden, die
    benötigten Utensilien und Stoffe direkt zu ihren Läden liefere.

   
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
</section>
   
   <br>


  <!-- großhandel--->
<section id="Großhandel">

 <h4>Ich bringe den Großhandel zu ihnen</h4>

 <img src="img/4444.jpg" alt="Großhandel">
 <br>
 <br>

 <p>

 Da das Hauptgeschäft des Kurzwarenmobils auf die Mobilität und große Auswahl ausgelegt ist  und ich die Waren direkt vom Großhandel beziehe,
 bin ich in der Lage die beste Ware zum günstigen Preis anzubieten. wodurch sie selbstverständlich bares Geld sparen können!
 <br>
 Umfangreiches Angebot und stets die aktuellsten Waren der Kurzwarenwelt, Ob Knöpfe und 
 Reißverschlüsse für individuelle Modeschöpfungen, Handarbeitsgarne oder modische
 Bänder und Kordeln für kreative Deko-Ideen: Das Kurzwarenmobil führt stehts eine Große Auswahl an hochwertigen
 Arbeitsmaterialien und das ohne Einschränkung und in voller Ausführung direkt vor ihrer Tür! 
 Durch regelmäßige Besuche und kostenloser Anfahrt können sie dadurch Einsparungen in ihren Lagerhaltungs- bzw Lieferungskosten einsparen.

 </p>

</section>


  <!-- individueller service-->

<section id="service">
 <br>


 <h4>Individueller Service</h4>

 <img src="img/222.jpg" alt="Sortiment innen">
 <br>
 <br>


 <p>

 Durch die Natur meiner Arbeit haben sie nicht nur den Vorteil, dass ich ihnen alle benötigten Utensilien bis vor die Türe bringe, sondern auch das Privileg sich am gesamten Katalog des Kurzwarenmobils vor Ort inspirieren und individuell beraten zu lassen. Fehlerhafte Bestellung gehören damit der vergangenheit an!
 
 

 </p>
 <br>
    
</section>

    <!-- Contact -->

<section id="Kontakt">
   <h3>Kontakt</h3>
   <hr>

   <form>
   <input class="input_text" type="email" tabindex="1" Placeholder="E-mail" ><br><br>
   <input class="input_text" type="text" tabindex="2" Placeholder="Betreff" ><br><br>
      <textarea class="input_text" tabindex="3" Placeholder="Nachricht" ></textarea> <br><br>
       <input class="button" type="submit">

   </form>
</section>

    <!-- Footer -->

  <footer>
   <p>
    &copy; 2018-2019 B.Ertürk, All rights reserved
   </p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Share a minimal HTML, CSS which shows us that the media queries are not working... then you'll get plenty of help pretty quick

Comment: Please add your html.

Comment: Can you please add your html ?

Comment: HTML is added, thanks for all your replies

Comment: Your code seems to work
Also you can check standard way to write media queries here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

Comment: I appreciate your answers, but somehow the H1 wont get smaller (>480) whereas the rest of the site is sized correctly

Comment: btw you also have some errors in your HTML, you can't have `<ul> -> <a> -> <li>`

Comment: thank you i will look into that, any other errors you noticed?

Answer (score 0):

> You can use media query like this.

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
    /** Style goes here **/

}

@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
    /** Style Style goes here **/
}


@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
    /** Style Style goes here **/
}
```

> or use media Query according to your need

Answer (score 0):

Your mediaqueries for navigtion and h1 (and all other elements) work fine.

`480px` does not mean mobile phone, nowadays it only works for old smartphones (like iphone 4?)

If you have a newer (like from the last 4-5 years) phone it will most probably not have a screen with 480px and therefore you don't see any smaller headline.

You should think about adding another breakpoint between 1024 and 480px, for current generation smartphones.

Edit: To show you that your code works:

I set the font-size of h1 in your code to 10px (and added some margin for demonstratino purposes)

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
 [...]
#home h1 {
    font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
 [...]
}
```

Then if you run the code, inspect the iframe in the result and set it's width to `300px` (or any width smaller than 480px really)

Then you get a result like this:

[image: iframe view]

This is the view in the dev-tools:

[image: dev tools view]

I didn't change anything else in your code, so you see your code for the h1 element work as it should.

```css
html, body{margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; text-align: center;}
section { min-height: 85%}
a {text-decoration: none;}
li {list-style-type: none;}

h1, h2, h3,a { font-family: "Roboto Slab", sans-serif ; font-weight: 500; color: #494949;text-transform: uppercase;}
h1, h2 {color: white;
text-shadow: 0 -1px #999999, 1px 0 #999999, 0 1px #999999, -1px 0 #999999;}
h3 {font-size: 40px; padding-top: 0%;margin-bottom: 5px;}
h4, p {font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif; color:#494949;}

/* h1 padding as solution for the "jump to home" problem :h1 {padding-top: 2.5%} *******/


hr {width: 100px;height: 3px;background: #494949;border: 0;margin: 0 auto 40px auto;}
#logo,li,img,.button {transition: all 300ms; -webkit-transition: all 300ms; -moz-transition: all 300ms; -o-transition: all 300ms}


/* HEADER ********************************/
header { width: 100%; height: 65px; position: fixed; top:0; left: 0; background: #FEFCFB; box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ; z-index: 1; }

 #logo {

 width: 140px;
 float: left;
 margin: 10px 0 0 -10px
 }

#logo img{

 width: 56%;


}

#logo:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}

 
header nav {

 float:right;
 margin:6px 50px 0 0;
}

header nav ul li {
 float:left;
 margin-left: 25px;
}

header nav ul li a {
 font-size: 16px
}

header nav ul li:hover {
 padding-top: 5px;
}
/* Header

#headerino {
 min-height: 10%
}
 ********************************/





/* Home ********************************/


#home{
 background: url(../img/landing.jpg);
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment:  fixed;
 }

#home h1 {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 70px;
 font-size: 110px}

#home h2 {
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 font-size: 25px;

}

#home img  {
 width: 32px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 opacity: 0.7;
}
#home img:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
#home {min-height: 100%}
/* About ********************************/


#about img {
 width: 240px;
}

#about h4{
 font-size: 15px;
}

#about p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;


}

#about img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* Kurzwarenmobil ********************************/

#DasKurzwarenmobil img {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 3px;


}
#DasKurzwarenmobil {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 opacity: 1;
}
#DasKurzwarenmobil p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 }

#DasKurzwarenmobil img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}



/* Ich bringe den Großhandel zu ihnen ********************************/
#Großhandel img {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 3px;}

 #Großhandel img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);
}

#Großhandel p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
/* Service ********************************/
#service img {
 width: 400px;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#service {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 opacity: 1;
}
#service img:hover {
 transform: scale(1.1);}

#service p{
 width: 70%;
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 }

/* Contact  ********************************/


form input, textarea {
font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
font-size: 15px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: #494949;
outline: none;
}

form input {

 width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 30px

}

form textarea {
 width: 552px;
 height: 200px;
 resize: none;
 border-color: #494949;
}


.input_text {
 color:#494949 ;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.button {

 width: 566px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #f0f0f0;
 color: #494949;
}

.button:hover {

 background-color: #494949;
 color: #f0f0f0;

}

/* Footer  ********************************/


footer {

width: 100%;
height: 70px;
background-color: #3f3f3f;
}

footer p {
 font-size: 12px;
 color: #f0f0f0;
 padding-top:30px;
}

/* Media Queries ********************************/






/* Tablets ********************************/

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){



#logo {
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}


header nav {
 margin-top: 10px;

}
header nav ul li {
 font-size: 12px;
}

#home h1 {
  margin-top: 120px;
 font-size: 65px;
}

#home h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
}
h3 {padding-top: 12%
}

}
/* Mobile********************************/

@media screen and (max-width:480px) {

#logo {
 width: 100px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}


header nav {
 margin-top: 10px;

}
header nav ul li {
 font-size: 12px;
}

#home h1 {
 font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

#home h2 {
 font-size: 22px;
}
h3 {padding-top: 12%
}

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <!-- Header -->
   <header>
 
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="img/111.jpg"="Kurzwarenmobil">
    </div>

    <nav>
    
     <ul>
      <a href="#index"><li>home</li></a>
      <a href="#about"><li>Über mich</li></a>
      <a href="#DasKurzwarenmobil"><li>Das Kurzwarenmobil</li></a>
      <a href="#Kontakt"><li>Kontakt</li></a>
     </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>


   <!-- Home -->
<section id="home">
     <h1>Kurzwarenmobil</h1>
     <h2>H.S. Schneiderbedarf</h2>
     <a href="#about">
     <img src="img/pfeil.png" alt="arrow">
     </a>
</section>


    <!-- Über mich -->

<section id="about">
    <h3>Über mich</h3>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Hüllis face">
    <h4>H.S Schneiderbedarf<h4>
    <p> 
     Ich Bin Hülya S. und habe mittlerweile mehr als ein Jahrzent Erfahrung im Schneider- sowie Kurzwarengeschäft angesammelt. 
    Meine Leidenschaft und Faszinierung der Branche gegenüber brachten mich
    nach jahrelangem arbeiten als Näherin in verschiedenen Unternehmen dazu, mich in dieser Branche selbstständig zu machen
    
    Nachdem die Entscheidung der Selbstständigkeit gefällt war, fing die Arbeit erst richtig an. Nach langem Konzeptionieren, Umsetzen, Verfeinern, Scheitern und wieder aufstehen war letzendlich die Idee des "Kurzwarenmobils" geboren.
    <br>

    Mittlerweile erstreckt sich mein Kundenstamm weit über die Grenzen Hannovers, den Heimatort des Kurzwarenmobils aus. Mittlerweile beläuft sich das Geschäft auf viele große sowie kleine Städte Norddeutschlands, und die Kapazitätsgrenze ist noch lange nicht erreicht.
   
   </p>
</section>


   <!-- Kurzwarenmobil -->

<section id="DasKurzwarenmobil">
    <br>
    <h3>Das Kurzwarenmobil</h3>
    <hr>
    <img src="img/333.jpg" alt="INSERT IMG Hülli WAGEN+ Sie">
    <h4>Was Ist das Kurzwarenmobil?</h4>
    <p>
     Das Kurzwarenmobil ist mein Transporter, mit dem ich täglich verschiedene Städte  Deutschlands besuche und meinen über 300 Kunden, die
    benötigten Utensilien und Stoffe direkt zu ihren Läden liefere.

   
    </p>
    <br>
    <br>
</section>
   
   <br>


  <!-- großhandel--->
<section id="Großhandel">

 <h4>Ich bringe den Großhandel zu ihnen</h4>

 <img src="img/4444.jpg" alt="Großhandel">
 <br>
 <br>

 <p>

 Da das Hauptgeschäft des Kurzwarenmobils auf die Mobilität und große Auswahl ausgelegt ist  und ich die Waren direkt vom Großhandel beziehe,
 bin ich in der Lage die beste Ware zum günstigen Preis anzubieten. wodurch sie selbstverständlich bares Geld sparen können!
 <br>
 Umfangreiches Angebot und stets die aktuellsten Waren der Kurzwarenwelt, Ob Knöpfe und 
 Reißverschlüsse für individuelle Modeschöpfungen, Handarbeitsgarne oder modische
 Bänder und Kordeln für kreative Deko-Ideen: Das Kurzwarenmobil führt stehts eine Große Auswahl an hochwertigen
 Arbeitsmaterialien und das ohne Einschränkung und in voller Ausführung direkt vor ihrer Tür! 
 Durch regelmäßige Besuche und kostenloser Anfahrt können sie dadurch Einsparungen in ihren Lagerhaltungs- bzw Lieferungskosten einsparen.

 </p>

</section>


  <!-- individueller service-->

<section id="service">
 <br>


 <h4>Individueller Service</h4>

 <img src="img/222.jpg" alt="Sortiment innen">
 <br>
 <br>


 <p>

 Durch die Natur meiner Arbeit haben sie nicht nur den Vorteil, dass ich ihnen alle benötigten Utensilien bis vor die Türe bringe, sondern auch das Privileg sich am gesamten Katalog des Kurzwarenmobils vor Ort inspirieren und individuell beraten zu lassen. Fehlerhafte Bestellung gehören damit der vergangenheit an!
 
 

 </p>
 <br>
    
</section>

    <!-- Contact -->

<section id="Kontakt">
   <h3>Kontakt</h3>
   <hr>

   <form>
   <input class="input_text" type="email" tabindex="1" Placeholder="E-mail" ><br><br>
   <input class="input_text" type="text" tabindex="2" Placeholder="Betreff" ><br><br>
      <textarea class="input_text" tabindex="3" Placeholder="Nachricht" ></textarea> <br><br>
       <input class="button" type="submit">

   </form>
</section>

    <!-- Footer -->

  <footer>
   <p>
    &copy; 2018-2019 B.Ertürk, All rights reserved
   </p>
  </footer>
```

Comment: But even when running my snippet, the H1 gets only smaller once (from Desktop to tablet), the rest works fine but the H1 doesnt go down in size from tablet size to smallest screen size,

Comment: Yes it does. If you open the browser dev tools and activate the screen resizing tools and set the dimensions to smaller than 480px the h1 will have a smaller fontsize. It is still too big to fit in one line so it overflows horizontally but the styles you specified are getting applied.

Comment: i set it to 1px on smallest screen size but the size won´t change at the last breakpoint... i used the screen resizing tool, can i post a video here? im really desperate^^ somehow it won´t apply it to the h1. 

Im really thankfull for all the replies

Comment: added my answer to show you that if you change the font-size it indeed changes. Feel free to add any additional info to your question if this doesn't cover all your problems.

Comment: oh wow... that kind of faults happen when the file you´re editing and the file you opened up in the browser aren´t the same :D

thanks for your patience, it works fine now!

Comment: btw (totally unrelated to your question), you use the `wrong` character for your apostrophes (or whatever they are called) .. It's not the one right next to backspace key, it's the one where you have to press `shift` + `#` key. That's correct. That´s not.

Comment: thank's also for that tip, my prof will appreciate it =D

Comment: Hey cloned, can I ask another question here before starting a new thread? 

I try to shrink down the size of the input fields of the form at the end, somehow only changing the width in the css dosn't seem to work, any idea how to fix that? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I can only say: If you change the width in CSS it works. See also my edit, I changed the width of the input elements to 50%